# Why doesn't drag and drop of grid rows work in Chrome like it does in FireFox?

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica version:  2020 R1 (20.102.0015)

I'm using the following example to code the grid row drag and drop functionality:

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/04/resort-grid-rows-with-drag-and-drop

This works fine in FireFox, but not at all in Chrome.   Is this a known issue - or is there something else I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: This is not helping in any way but if it doesn't work in Edge/Safari than the underlying reason it doesn't work is Chromium/WebKit. You can open a ticket with Acumatica if you have a support contract.

Comment: If it is at all possible to make it work in Chromium/WebKit. That would be a workaround involving flags configuration. Ex: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/input-dev/c/iQ5Vy3iTAPw

Comment: It seems to work in 2021 R2 - so this may be a moot point once we upgrade.   Thanks, all...

Comment: Great, I suspect Chromium removed an old compatibility flag which introduced a breaking change in Acumatica. This occured for lazy-frame loading as well (empty frame bug).